# Foursquare: improper venue response

Tags: api, foursquare

I use the foursquare API to query nearby locations according to `categoryID`s. I require preliminary information about the operation hours of the venue as well as if the venue is currently open to do early pruning, and have a large relevant venue response; and from `Foursquare` documentation can only be done in `explore`. And then check exact hours of all venues queried in separate calls.

Because of this I use `explore` over `search`; however, I recently implemented the categoryIDs since I do not intend to search by natural language query but by category ID and have found that their are many venues missing in a given area that works in say a normal query. For example if I pass Food as a query I get more results than if i pass its categoryID `4d4b7105d754a06374d81259`. What would cause this?

The code I have is pretty spread out and most of it would be irrelevant anyway. Any assistance would be well appreciated?

**EDIT:**

Just to add, I generally commented out the search radius and it stayed roughly in the closed surrounding area. After I switched to the category IDs I zoomed out and have found that the search radius is increased to what I actually intended it to be; however, it is still not tracking all of the bussiness close by to the search area For example It picks up `Chipotle` but `5Guys`, `Subway` and `McDonalds` are ignored though they appeared when I did a query for `Food`.

**EDIT:**

Also even though I checked with individual category ID's I generally simply add multiple IDs to the categoryID field of the search query